# Add POSTed JSON to database

Tags: android, database, django, json, http

I have an Android application published, which shows the user the traffic conditions in the zone he wants, and can be filtered by road, by km... Well, that doesn't matter.

I want to know when the app is more used (weekends? During week at the morning?) and how the users use it, so I'm developing a way to get the user's use of the app.

**First of all, I want to remark that this is going to be completely anonymous, and no personal data will be registered**, and of course it will be disabled by default, only activated if the user wants it.

After pointing that, I'm going with the question.

I've developed a way to get the user usage in a JSON, and I'd want to upload it (probably via HTTP POST) and save it to a database, in my hosting.

I've thought in using Django, but I don't know which would be the best framework/method to do it.

What do you reccomend me to do that?

Comment: What has the Android to do with it?

Comment: The Android app generates the JSON (that part is completely covered). I'm asking about some online tool where the app can send it and add automatically add it to a database. Maybe Django and sending the JSON via HTTP POST? (It's only an idea. I'm asking for advice)

Comment: You can do it with a simple php script too!

Comment: How? Passing the JSON to the PHP?
I have no idea about how to do it... Is it possible with PHP taking this info and adding it to a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this little tutorial and i think it's what you want!

[Send And Receive JSON to PHP Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php)

Comment: This has helped me A LOT to understand how to manage PHP requests, so first of all, thank you very much!

Finally I'm going to do it with an HTTP GET connection, passing the JSON as a String, and after, parsing it with PHP and adding it to the database